# Vuetify, align button next to text field

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a text field and on right of the text field a button is appended.
My issue is that the button has a top margin and is not in line with the text field. As you can see in the following picture, the button is too low.

**Example:**

[image: The button is not aligned with the text field]

**Question:**

How can i align the button with the text field in a native way?

I tried applying class="mt-0" to the button but that did not change anything.

**Code:**

```
<v-row>
  <v-col md="6" offset-md="3">
    <v-text-field class="pt-5" placeholder="Strawberries" outlined clearable>
      <!-- <template slot="append">
        <v-icon>clear</v-icon>
      </template> -->
      <template slot="append-outer">
        <v-btn dark x-large color="pink"> SEARCH </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
<v-row>
    <v-text-field class="pt-5" placeholder="Strawberries" outlined clearable></v-text-field>
    <v-btn dark x-large color="pink"> SEARCH </v-btn>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `d-flex` is better than `v-row` as `v-row` removes spacing and other stuff.

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <v-text-field class="pt-5 mr-2" placeholder="Strawberries" outlined clearable></v-text-field>
    <v-btn dark x-large color="pink"> SEARCH </v-btn>
</div>
```

`v-row`

[image]

`d-flex`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the only simple solution I could find was to add `hide-details` to the `v-text-field`. But unfortunately this removes the validation messaging if this is something you need.